# Application without storyboard black panels on top and bottom

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, swift

I'm trying to start an application without any layout files (Storyboard etc.) I removed the storyboard file and references to it. Now when I'm starting an UIViewController manually from appdelegate, weird black panels comes on the top and on the bottom of the screen.

Appdelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    var svc = SessionsViewController()
    self.window?.rootViewController = svc
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

[image: Here is how the application looks like]

What is causing this and how to avoid it?

Comment: Do you see the same issue when running a 4" simulator?

Comment: Hi @Cabus! Seems that the black bars disappears with ios 4 simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your app is launching the version for a smaller phone size.

You need to at least define launch images for each iPhone size you want to make your app available for.